# Select statement with .$row

Tags: php, mysql

I wonder what is wrong with this select statement.
this is the error i am getting:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE,
>   expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in
>   /home/www/mp28.bit-mp.biz/CardRegistration2.php on line 47

```
$query = "SELECT PlayerName FROM Players where TeamName = .$row['Team1']";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT PlayerName FROM Players where TeamName = .$row['Team1']";
```

should be

```
$query = "SELECT PlayerName FROM Players where TeamName = '{$row['Team1']}'";
```

Comment: I want to populate a dropdown list with values from two different columns

e.g. Away vs Home
     xxx  vs yyy

I want to populate a dropdowlist: 

--select--
xxx
yyy
 
Anyone can help me with this??

Answer (score 0):

Query correction check two solutions. Both should work:

```
$query = "SELECT PlayerName FROM Players where TeamName =" .$row['Team1'];
```

OR

```
$query = "SELECT PlayerName FROM Players where TeamName ='" .$row['Team1'] . "'";
```

Concatenation issue at `TeamName =`

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT PlayerName FROM Players where TeamName = '".$row['Team1']."' ";
```

Try this. TeamName column is varchar so passing string enclosed with `quotes`.